# length of trademark symbol in python 2.x

Tags: encoding, python-2.7

why is

```
>>> len('™')
>>> 3
```

in python 2.x?

how can I quickly fix it to be considered as one character (like Python 3.x?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminal encoding is set to UTF8. You are counting the bytes in the encoded character:

```
>>> '™'
'\xe2\x84\xa2'
>>> len('™')
3
```

Use unicode to count characters instead of bytes:

```
>>> u'™'
u'\u2122'
>>> len(u'™')
1
```

or *decode* from the terminal encoding:

```
>>> import sys
>>> '™'.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
u'\u2122'
```

In Python 3, strings are `unicode` values, with the Python 2 `str` type renamed to `byte` (your input is essentially the same as `b'™'` in Python 3).

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky